# React Native Upload to YouTube

Tags: reactjs, video, react-native, file-upload, youtube

I am trying to upload a video that I take locally using react native camera and then send it to youtube for processing and then want to display that video on a react.js web dashboard.

We have tried using fetch-blob to upload the video and cloud firestore to store the video. We are not sure at a high level on how to go about the uploading to youtube. I know there is upload docs, however can we physically go about uploading straight from our react-native project to youtube, or would we have to upload to a database such as firebase and then use a cloud function to send it to youtube? Has anyone attempted this? The other alternative is that we can upload to S3 and then use AWS cloudstream to play back but that seems like overkill if there is a simple youtube upload that we can use. Do we have to authenticate a user to youtube before it would work? We do not want anyone having to log into a google account. We are hoping just to have an application created with youtube that we can upload to our channel.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

**Answer**

You can absolutely upload a video to YouTube in many different ways. You mentioned a few options and I will line out how those could work for you.

> Do we have to authenticate a user to youtube before it would work?

You will have to authenticate to YouTube in order to upload to a YouTube account. You could very well have one account for your app to use and when your users make videos the app could upload them directly to that account. I do highly advise against that though. Google is not very forgiving and the second someone uploads something to violate Google Policies I suspect you will be banned.

That leaves me to believe the best way here would be to use Auth0 to authenticate users and upload to their accounts. Otherwise maybe look into other options.

***Possible Options***

*Option 1*

It might be possible to upload all the videos to one YouTube account and make them all private. Then retrieve those videos and play them on your own site. Possibly something like that could work but it is probably a long shot. That could at least keep you from getting banned because of a user violating Google Policies.

*Option 2*

Another option would be to make one YouTube account. Save the videos to your server when the users creates them from your mobile application. Then have a waiting period for the video to post to YouTube in order for you and your team to have time to approve them.

At least this way you can use YouTube and have one account, but not take the chance of any repercussions from the videos people are posting.

**Problem**

How to upload a video from your mobile app using React Native to youtube.com

**Solution 1**

Upload straight from React Native. You can Use the `Google APIs` to upload directly to youtube. Google has an extensive API. You will have to create a Google API account and make sure to activate the APIs you want to use. Here is some information I found using the `Google Javascript API` to work with Youtube.

If you go to this [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/client-side-web-apps) you can see some information on the scopes of this API.

Here is one scope mentioned on that page.

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload

Using Gogoles APIs you can upload videos directly to the youtube account.

**Solution 2**

The second solution is to post the video to your server, then once it hits the server use some other server side language to interact with `Google's API`. This could come in handy for other reasons. Like if you are better with a language other than `JavaScript`. For example `Python` might be your favorite language. In that case [here is a Python Github repo](https://github.com/tokland/youtube-upload) that does just what your trying to do.

You could very well implement the repo mentioned above to your server and post the video you create from your phone to the server. Allowing the `Python` script to handle posting the video to YouTube.

**Side Note**

I do not think `Firebase` or really any `database` is necessary for the task you are trying to accomplish. Unless there are other requirements to your problem you have not mentioned.